# Can I use a single gateway with multiple/2 lan cards in linux

Tags: network-interface

I have two interfaces eth0 and eth1 in the same network

```
eth0 ip : 192.168.10.10
gateway : 192.168.10.5

eth1 IP : 192.168.10.11
```

Can I use the same gateway?

```
192.168.10.5  for eth1
```

I am able to ping only a single interface which has a gateway. I need to access both the IP addresses from a different network.

Note: it works when I am using alias of eth0 but not with a different interface.

Comment: This should just work, as long as you don't mess with routes. I don't see what the use is however, as the first interface will be used for both IP addresses. Perhaps you should investigate interface bonding (if your switch supports this).

Comment: You're likely going to be struggling with issues for a long time trying to work out all the kinks of having 2 interfaces on the same subnet. However to solve the specific issue you are reporting, you need to `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=0`